# Join two tables to produce a given output

Tags: mysql

```
describe user;

 id       int(1)       NO    'PRI'  0             
 name     'varchar'(20)  YES        NULL           
 address  'varchar'(20)  YES        NULL          
 class    int(2)       YES        NULL           
 DOB      date         YES        NULL           
 created  date         YES        NULL 


describe 'marklist'
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | int(1)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| subject     | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 'markscored'| int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 'outof'     | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 'userid'    | int(2)      | YES  |'NUL'| NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

these are the two tables given and from these two i require an out put to be as :

```
|name |class|biology|chemistry|physics|outoftotal|totalmarkscored|percentage|
+-----+-----+-------+---------+-------+----------+---------------+----------+
|arun | 5   |  45   |  42     |  40   |  150     | 127           |84.6      |
```

kindly give me a query to get the above output using the two tables user and marklist'

Comment: Please format your code.  Indent each line with 4 or more spaces.

Comment: by using the below query i get my required output

Comment: SELECT  u.name,u.class,
SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'biology' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS biology,
SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'chemistry' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS chemistry,
SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'physics' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS physics,
SUM( markscored) AS TOTAL,
SUM(outof) AS OUTOF
FROM  u, marklist m
WHERE u.id=m.userid
GROUP BY u.name,u.class;

Answer (score 0):

btw, it's weird that int(2) have '150'.

'user' is also a reserved word in sql so dont use it pls

```
SELECT u.name,u.class,
(SELECT SUM(subject) FROM marklist WHERE subject LIKE 'biology') AS biology,
(SELECT SUM(subject) FROM marklist WHERE subject LIKE 'chemistry') AS chemistry,m.outof AS outoftotal,m.markscored AS     
totalmarkscored,m.markscored/m.outof*100
FROM user u, marklist m
WHERE u.id=m.id
```

Comment: the `(2)` is just optional display width and can store the full range of `int` datatype Reference:[Numeric Type Attributes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)

Comment: wow, I didnt know about that.Good to know @bansi But still isn't it supposed to be int(3)?

Comment: sir, i want an output as  field list :-name,class,markscored,totalmarkscored,total outof,and eliminate the rows  subject and add rows like biology,chemistry,physics etc, pls kindly give me a query to insert biology,chemistry,physics as rows

Comment: is that what you mean @Gowrisankar? because I dont know where the 45 or 42 comes from

Comment: SELECT u.name,u.class,
(SELECT SUM( markscored) FROM marklist WHERE subject LIKE 'biology' ) AS biology,
(SELECT SUM( markscored) FROM marklist WHERE subject LIKE 'chemistry' ) AS chemistry,
(SELECT SUM( markscored) FROM marklist WHERE subject LIKE 'physics' ) AS physics,
(SELECT SUM( markscored) FROM marklist ) AS total,
(SELECT SUM(outof) FROM marklist) AS outof,
((SELECT SUM( markscored) FROM marklist)/(SELECT SUM(outof) FROM marklist)*100) as p
FROM  u, marklist m
WHERE u.id=m.userid;   by using the above query i get a output as  table having repeated arun, can you please reply

Comment: what does this sentance mean?->"by using the above query i get a output as table having repeated arun"

Answer (score 0):

thanking you MVCNoob, after executing the modified query :
 SELECT u.id,u.name,u.class,
 (SELECT SUM( markscored) FROM marklist WHERE subject LIKE 'biology' AND  u.id=m.id) AS biology,
 (SELECT SUM( markscored) FROM marklist WHERE subject LIKE 'chemistry' AND u.id=m.id) AS chemistry,
 (SELECT SUM( markscored) FROM marklist WHERE subject LIKE 'physics' AND u.id=m.id) AS physics,
 (SELECT SUM( markscored) FROM marklist WHERE u.id=m.id) AS total,
 (SELECT SUM(outof) FROM marklist WHERE u.id=m.id) AS outof,
 ((SELECT SUM( markscored) FROM marklist WHERE u.id=m.id)/(SELECT SUM(outof) FROM marklist WHERE u.id=m.id)*100) as p
 FROM  u, marklist m
 WHERE u.id=m.userid=1; , i get an output as:
+------+------+-------+---------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+---------+
| id   | name | class | biology | chemistry | physics | total | outof | p       |
+------+------+-------+---------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+---------+
|    1 | Arun |     6 |      37 |        48 |      48 |   133 |   150 | 88.6667 |
|    1 | Arun |     6 |    NULL |      NULL |    NULL |  NULL |  NULL |    NULL |
|    1 | Arun |     6 |    NULL |      NULL |    NULL |  NULL |  NULL |    NULL |
+------+------+-------+---------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec), here  arun is repeating pls kindly let me a query to avoid the repeation
thanking you